# Delete duplicate lines in two sentence aligned files, Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, duplicates

I have a parallel corpora in two files (one in German, the other in English) where sentences are aligned. It means that on each line of a file, the same line in the other file contains its traduction.

However, in the german corpora, some sentences are still in English (or they are just weird tags) for example :

```
file.en, line 500: The house is small    file.de, line 500: Das Haus ist klein
file.en, line 501: The cat is big        file.de, line 501: The cat is big
file.en, line 444: EMEA/CVMP/424/01      file.de, line 444: EMEA/CVMP/424/01
```

As I need to preserve the order of the sentences, I would like to detect such duplicates (`string1 == string2`) and remove them from both files, so that the sentences are still aligned afterward.

I have seen some solutions with `awk`, but none that match my problem.

Any thought ?

NOTE : The files are several million lines big.

Comment: Are all line in the same order in both files?

Comment: And you want to overwrite the originals?

Comment: Well I can output the processing in two other sperate files too, as long as I have 2 files that are still sentence aligned after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a small perl script which won't need to store anything but the immediate line in memory.

Just compares both files line by line and only prints different ones.

```
use warnings;
use strict;


open(my $fh1,'<','file');
open(my $fh2,'<','file2');
open(my $fh3,'>','outfile');
open(my $fh4,'>','outfile2');

while (my $line  = <$fh1>){
        my $line2 = <$fh2> ;
        if($line ne $line2){
                print $fh3 $line;
                print $fh4 $line2;
        }
}
```

use as

```
perl script.pl
```

Answer (score 3):

Just learning awk :) so here's my solution:

```
paste file.en file.de -d@ | awk 'BEGIN{FS="@";}{if ($1 != $2) {print $1 > "file.en_fixed"; print $2 > "file.de_fixed";}}'
```

Tested it and it works.

Shorter version, thanks to 123:

```
paste file.en file.de -d@ | awk 'BEGIN{FS="@";}$1 != $2{print $1 > "file.en_fixed"; print $2 > "file.de_fixed";}'
```

Comment: Nice , don't need the if though `$1 != $2{print $1 > "file.en_fixed"; print $2 > "file.de_fixed"}` with no outer block will work.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Nice solution ! I used it to remove the duplicate lines in both files by changing `$1 != $2` with `!seen[$0]++` and it seems to work very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using Python:

```
f = open('input_file', 'r')
out = open('out_file', 'w')
for line in f.readlines():                                                      
    x = line.split('file')[1].split(':')[-1].split()
    y = line.split('file')[-1].split(':')[-1].split()

    if x != y:      
        out.write(line)
```